# Vagrant VMWare Plugin - Show VM in VMWare Workstation

Tags: vagrant, vmware-workstation

I'm using Vagrant with the VMWare plugin. I've noticed that VMs upped using Vagrant are not displayed automatically in the VMWare Workstation GUI.

I can (manually) open them using *File->Open...* and selecting the **.vagrant\machines\puppet\vmware_workstation\some-unique-id...vmx** file. But that's a bit annoying. Using VirtualBox, vagrant VMs are automatically added and removed from the Virtualbox GUI.

Am I missing something or is that just not supported for VMWare boxes?

Reaons why I'm not just sticking with vagrant commands:

1. To quickly see which machines are running (I have multiple machine setups and yes, I know vagrant status does the same...)
2. To create and restore snapshots (I have a time consuming provisioning and sometimes it's nice to just restore to a snapshot while testing)

Comment: You needn't care of vmware when run vagrant, `vagrant up, vagrant ssh, vagrant halt` should be fine to manage your vagrant instance. Take a look on `vagrant help`

Comment: Yes, I know. However, there are a few situations where using the provider GUI is helpful/necessary. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much to do about #1, it looks like VMWare limitation.

However you can use [this Vagrant plugin](https://github.com/scalefactory/vagrant-multiprovider-snap) to add snapshot ability from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the plugin. Pretty much does what I need!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get @mmey's exact solution to work, but putting this in the `Vagrantfile` worked for me:

```
config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

[Documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vmware/configuration.html)

Comment: I had a minor typo in my answer (provicer instead of provider...) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the (not so surprising) answer to my question: Just disable headless mode by setting `config.vm.provider.gui=true` in the Vagrantfile (as described at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vmware/configuration.html).

Comment: The confusing thing is that Virtualbox always displays the VMs on Windows, regardless of headless mode.